# Program seems to be executing both if statements

Tags: c++

So I need the program to execute either one of the if statements that meet the conditions I've put. The input I used was 70, 15, and 30,000.It should go into the second if statement.Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int information1(int hourR);
int information2(int conTime);
int information3(int income1);
int hourR,conTime,income1;
ofstream outfile;

int information1(int hourR)
{
  cout<<"Enter hourly rate.";
  cin>>hourR;
  return hourR;
}

int information2(int conTime)
{
  cout<<"Enter total consulting time in minutes.";
  cin>>conTime;
  return conTime;
}

int information3(int income1)
{
  cout<<"Enter income.";
  cin>>income1;
  return income1;
}

int main()
{
  int hours,consultTime,income,fortyPercent,seventyPercent;
  outfile.open("Billing amount.txt");
  hours=information1(hourR);
  consultTime=information2(conTime);
  income=information3(income1);


if(income<=25000) {
if(consultTime<=30) {
outfile<<"No service charge.";
}
else {

    fortyPercent=hours*.4*45/60;
    outfile<<fortyPercent;
    }
}

else
{
if(consultTime<=20){

outfile<<"No service charge.";
}   
else
{
seventyPercent=hours*.7*45/60;
outfile<<seventyPercent;
}
}
      outfile.close();
      return 0;
    }
```

Also can any1 tell me whether im doing the calculations right?becuz its confusing me,here is the problem.

During the tax season, every Friday, the J&J accounting firm provides assistance
to people who prepare their own tax returns. Their charges are as follows:

a. If a person has low income (<=25,000) and the consulting time is less
than or equal to 30 minutes, there are no charges; otherwise, the service
charges are 40% of the regular hourly rate for the time over 30 minutes.

b. For others, if the consulting time is less than or equal to 20 minutes, there
are no service charges; otherwise, service charges are 70% of the regular
hourly rate for the time over 20 minutes.

(For example, suppose that a person has low income and spent 1 hour and 15 minutes,
and the hourly rate is $70.00. Then the billing amount is 70.00*0.40*(45 / 60)=
$21.00.)

Comment: Why do you believe it would not execute both if statements?

Comment: Improve code formatting!!!!

Comment: at the moment it does execute both,but i need it to execute one of them.Like for the input i used,i get 21No services charges in my output file.

Comment: @user2812652 So clarify on input and conditions ... And start to debug your program!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you currently have looks like this:

```
if(someCondition) {
     //doStuff
} else {
     //do something else
}

if(someOtherCondition) {
    //do stuff
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

The code will go execute either the `if` or the `else` for the FIRST `if else` pair AND either the `if` or the `else` for the SECOND pair.

The easiest solution I can think of looks like this:

```
if(income<=25000) {
    if(consultTime<=30) {
        //do stuff
    } else { //this else is paired with if(consultTime<30) and within the if(income<=30)
        //do stuff when income<=25000 and consultTime>30
    }
} else /*income>250000*/ { //this else is paired with if(income<=25000)
    if(consultTime<=20) {
        //do stuff
    } else { //this else is paired with if(consultTime<=20) and within the else paired with if(income<=30)
       //do stuff when income>25000 and consultTime>20
    }
}
```

Comment: I did your changes but i get 21No service charge.Do you know where the 21 might have come from?

Comment: Edit your changes into the original question.  Don't post it in comments.

Comment: @user2812652 21 is the expected answer from: hours*.4*45/60 when hours = 70. It does not seem like you changed your original code to make it use the solution in this answer however.

Comment: @user2812652 Without you posted the code you implemented into the original question so I can see how you actually implemented it, I can only GUESS as the why you're program is doing anything.  If you want further assistance (which I can only assume you do, as you haven't accepted my answer yet), you need to edit the original question to include your attempt at implementing the code I've posted.